# Jenkins/Hudson Dynamic content display

Tags: javascript, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have requirement like to enter some text in text box in builder/buildwrapper which will interact with db & fetch some data. This data i need to display in UI before building the job.I can check those some values among return data for the build.

Issues i am facing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("name");
        x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
        var y =document.getElementById("dataselect");   
        var z=${descriptor.getMyString(x.value)};

    }
```

when i am trying call a descriptor method to get the value it doesnot accept x.value where if i pass string it accepts & returns the data.

Secondly when i am trying to update the selector list using javascript it doesn't work in jelly.

Can you please provide me the plugin where i can refer for similar type of task or help me to resolve this issue.

```
 <f:entry title="Dataselect" field="dataselect">
   <f:select multiple="multiple" id="dataselect"/>
 </f:entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I able to resolve the issue, Here the  [Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/UI+Samples+Plugin) to look into.

or [Hudson Plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.hudson.main/ui-samples-plugin)

The javascript not required. doFillNumberitems(@Queryparameter textdata) resolved the issue along with below layout.

```
<?jelly escape-by-default='true'?>
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:s="/lib/samples">

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>      
 <f:entry>
  <s:sample>
    <form>
      <table>
        <f:entry title="Enter Text" field="textdata">
          <f:textbox />
        </f:entry>
        <f:entry>
          <j:forEach var="item" items="${instance.textdata}">
              <label for="${item}" style="color:#9933FF;font-weight: bold">*   ${item}</label><br/>
          </j:forEach>
        </f:entry>
        <f:entry title="Random Number" field="number">
          <f:select multiple="multiple"/>
        </f:entry>
      </table>
    </form>
  </s:sample>
  </f:entry>
</j:jelly>
```